# How can I send data from my main.js to my index.html (Electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am a complete beginner to JavaScript and Electron just so you know.

I think I've looked most places, and I haven't found a thing.

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>??</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <button id="get-data" type="submit">Get Data</button>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### main.js

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const ipc = require("electron").ipcMain;

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    const window = new BrowserWindow({
        "center": true,
        "width": 500,
        "height": 800,
        "webPreferences": {
            "nodeIntegration": true
        }
    });
    window.loadFile("index.html");
});

ipc.on("uhhm", event => {
    event.sender.send("ok", "Hello World!");
});
```

#### script.js

```js
const ipc = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
const getDataBtn = document.getElementById("get-data");

getDataBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    ipc.send("uhhm");
    ipc.once("ok", data => {
        getDataBtn.innerHTML = "Moving On... " + data;
    });
});
```

#### I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at script.js:1
```

IDK what to do

Have any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [communication between 2 browser windows in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251411/communication-between-2-browser-windows-in-electron)

Answer (score 3):

if you are using a >= 5 version of Electron, you need to enable the nodeIntegration and contextIsolation parameters as follows:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yesss thanks, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68217236/how-can-i-send-data-from-my-main-js-to-my-index-html-electron#:~:text=contextIsolation:%20false,) worked

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue when I worked for a while with Electron Framework, where I need IPC communication between a renderer process and the main process. The renderer process sits in an HTML file between script tags and generates the same error.

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
//throws the Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

In your case :

```
const ipc = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
```

You must to work around that by specifying Node.js integration as true when the browser window (where this HTML file is embedded) was originally created in the main process.

```
function createWindow() {

    // Create a new window
   const window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 300,
        height: 200,

        // The lines below solved the issue
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
})}
```

That solved the issue for me. The solution was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined/55908510#55908510).